# Can't I call function in function in python?

Tags: python, class

Below is a part of my code.

```
class Financial_Statements:
    def __init__(self,API_KEY,company_code,year,report_sort):
        self.API_KEY = API_KEY
        self.company_code = company_code
        self.year = year
        self.report_sort =report_sort


    def get_request(self):
        request= Request('https://opendart.fss.or.kr/api/fnlttSinglAcnt.json?crtfc_key='+self.API_KEY+'&corp_code='+self.company_code+'&bsns_year='+self.year+'&reprt_code='+self.report_sort)

        response = urlopen(request)
        elevations = response.read()
        data = json.loads(elevations)
        data = json_normalize(data['list']) ##--- json to dataframe
        data = data.loc[:,['fs_nm','sj_nm','account_nm','thstrm_dt','thstrm_amount','frmtrm_nm','frmtrm_amount','bfefrmtrm_nm','bfefrmtrm_amount']] 
        return data



    def get_financial_stock_price(self,reo = 0):
        data = get_request(self)
```

I define `def get_request` to get data and use it in other functions, but when I run the code it returns `'get_request' is not defined`.

Can't I use a function inside another function?

Comment: Use `self.get_request()` to call it from within the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the function inside the class, you have to call it with self. The appropriate code should be `self.get_request()`